# How can I vertically center :after content

Tags: html, css

I am using :after content like so

```
.img-div:after {
    content: ".01";
    position: absolute;
    width: 76.9%;
    height: 55%;
    top: 10%;
    right: 2.5%;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #6758ef;
    opacity: .8;
    font-size: 59px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I want to know that how can I vertically center the content property.

NOTE: I cannot use :before because I have it already for other purpose

https://jsfiddle.net/tfkt5411/

Comment: You have to add some more context by adding your `:before` and parent element as well to get more prompt answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try This:**

```
.img-div:after {
     line-height:197px;
     //Other codes...
}
```

> 197px is equal height(55%).

See [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tfkt5411/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

```css
.img-div-parent{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #6758ef;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
.img-div:after {
    content: ".01";
    position: relative;
    width: 76.9%;
    height: 55%;
    right: 2.5%;
    opacity: .8;
    font-size: 59px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-div-parent">
    <div class="img-div">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

you can specify the `width`, `height` and `background` for `.img-div` then you can use `:after` easily to center the content vertically and horizontally as well, check the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o92ob8yk/2/).

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.img-div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.img-div:after {
  content: ".01";
  width: 76.9%;
  height: 55%;
  background-color: #6758ef;
  opacity: .8;
  font-size: 59px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-div"></div>
```